# What is the difference between E-Science Infrastructures and Distributed Computing Infrastructures?

Tags: computer-science, distributed-computing, grid-computing

What is the difference between [eScience](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-Science) infrastructures and grid computing or distributed computing infrastructures? And what are some of their examples.

I can not distinguish them clearly. Is it how a grid is used make it an e-science platform?

Answer (score 0):

eScience infrastructures is grid computing, it's an application of distributed systems.  A sub-catagory, I suppose.